Merged Paris 2024 Medals Table
What happened to this Olympic Games Paris 2024 Medals Table?



Country
Gold
Silver
Bronze
Total




People's Republic of China
9
3
2
14


United States of America
5
9
5
19


France
5
5
5
15


Netherlands
5
1
1
7


Japan
5
1
2
8


Great Britain
3
5
2
10


Germany
3
2
4
9


New Zealand
3
1
1
5


Republic of Korea
2
2
1
5


Spain
2

1
3


Hungary
2


2


Australia
1
3
5
9


Italy
1
2
1
4


Sweden
1
1

2


Canada
1

4
5


Denmark
1

1
2


Brazil
1

2
3



knowledge tag is here because you might need for instance Wikipedia, such as this page.

Was the "Argent" intentional?

@Nautilus, it was not, thank you for helping improving the puzzle :)

Will it change with new medals?

@Nautilus, I'll consider answering your question in a future hint :)

Should Japan be above Netherlands, and Brazil above Denmark, or is the table intentionally not completely sorted?
